# How to improve Image resolution

Tags: android, json, image, android-volley, resolution

```
 String urlThumnail = currentNewsItem.getUrlThumbnail();


            loadImages(urlThumnail, newsHolder);
            break;

        case 2:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }


}

private void loadImages(String urlThumbnail, final NewsViewHolder holder) {
    if (urlThumbnail != null) {
        imageLoader.get(urlThumbnail, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
                holder.thumbnail.setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());
            }

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

xml

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/DetailsNewsImage_cardView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/DetailNews_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="195dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop">
```

I want to improve the resolution of the image, I am receiving image through JSon, then I have enlarged its size in Xml after loading it. The image that I am receiving after all this is blurred. I wish to improve the image resolution just like the original image.  How do I improve image resolution?

Comment: Is image you are trying to load large enough to fit your ImageView? Because if the image is smaller than your view, it will always expand and have lower resolution. You may try resizing the original image with resizing tools, then retrieve it to maybe lower the quality loss.

Comment: Yes, the ImageView is bigger that the original image itself. Is there a way I can improve Image resolution when enlarged?

Comment: I don't think you can. You should do it before downloading the image

Comment: Kindly, explain how I can achieve that?

Comment: I'm not talking about by coding. If you have direct access to those images, resize them with image resizing tools, then download them in your code. That's the only way I know for high quality images